# Fail to Update an entity contain an image field

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have an event entity ,

-The admin create the event and can update all fields

-The user can just update some fields (In my case I have an image field can’t be update by the user)

My problem is when the user update the event I have an error ! How can I fix that?

**The Error:**

```
The file could not be found. 
    Caused by: 
               ConstraintViolation {#601 ▼
               root: Form {#788 ▶}
               path: "data.image"
               value: "C:\wamp64\tmp\php4F0E.tmp"
            }
```

**Event entity**

```
class Event implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 *    @Assert\Image(
 *     minWidth = 60,
 *     maxWidth = 400,
 *     minHeight = 60,
 * )
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $image;
}
```

**I didn’t put the image field because the user dont have the permission to updateit**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('eventName')
            ->add('eventAdresse')
            ->add('eventAdresse')
            ->add('startEventDate', DateType::class, array(
         'widget' => 'single_text',     
         'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
           ->add('endEventDate', DateType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'))

}
```

**The controller**

```
class EventController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $event = $this->getUser();

        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\EventType',$event);

        $form ->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();


            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('event_homepage');
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Event:index.html.twig', array(
            'event' => $event,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

**Update:**
this is my code the first time when the admin add an event I have followed this document
https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

**in the database the path persisted is just the name of the file: 1cd665f6d16f13d7b293616dcee077d2.png?**

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $event=new Event();
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\EventType,$event);

    $form ->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
        $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($event);
        $password = $encoder->encodePassword($event->getPassword(), $event
->getSalt());
        $event->setPassword($password);




        if($event ->getImage()){
            $file = $event->getImage();

            // Generate a unique name for the file before saving it
            $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

            // Move the file to the directory where brochures are stored
            $file->move(
                $this->getParameter('images_directory_event'),
                $fileName
            );
            $event ->setImage($fileName);
        }



        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($event);


        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('administrator_event');
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Event:add.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));


}
```

**IN  parameters.yml**

```
images_directory_event: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/imagesEvent'
```

Comment: Possible solution is validation groups: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html / http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_based_validation.html

Answer (score 1):

You're saving the location of the file when uploading, which is a temporary file and will not stay permanently.  You have to manually move the file to the location that you want, and then update your entity accordingly.  You are getting a validation error because even though you're not editing that field, you are still performing Symfony validation on it, and the file no longer exists.

Take a look at the [Symfony documentation for file uploads](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html) for more help.  When first persisting the entity you'll want to do something like this:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\EventType', new Event());
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $file = $event->getImage();
        $fileName = 'the-file-name-you-choose.'.$file->guessExtension();

        $file->move('/the/upload/directory', $fileName);

        $event->setImage($fileName);

        $em->persist($event);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('wherever_you_want'));
    }

    return $this->render('event/new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: This exactly what I have done  in the frist add I have updated my post with my code is it a validation problem as andrew mentioned?

Comment: With the updated code, now what sort of issues/error messages are you getting?

Comment: The same error persist but what I have remarked is that in database  is the name of the file not the path 1cd665f6d16f13d7b293616dcee077d2.png